# Why do I have a different jump list for Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, jumplist

I understand that the Windows 7 jump list for Outlook 2007 should look something like the one on the left, whereas mine, on the right contains only the three basic items and an ICS file I imported recently.

I would like to have access to the commands for creating new items from my jump list. Can anyone explain why I don't get the other commands and what I might be able to do to enable them?

[image: Screenshots comparing Outlook 2007 jump lists]

UPDATE: Just after posting this I noticed that Outlook wasn't pinned to my task bar and thought this might be the cause of the problem. Pinning it only changed the Pin command to Unpin though, and had no effect otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot on the left is Outlook **2010**, this presumably had work done on it to make it make it work fully with all of Windows 7's new bells and whistles.

The screenshot on the right is Outlook **2007**, and is exactly what I see on my Windows 7 machine with Outlook 2007. As Outlook 2007 pre-dates Windows 7 by a couple of years it wasn't able to launch with all the fancy new Win 7 integration features. They may be added in an update, but if so it's not one that's reached my machine yet.